# RingCentral fax delivery times

Tags: fax, ringcentral

Are there any upper limits on time taken to deliver fax messages sent by Ring Central?

I have seen delivery times ranging from a few mins to well over an hour. And the same is concerning as we need some defined upper bound (5 min or less) on fax delivery times, especially for time sensitive messages.

I did go through the RingCentral dev docs and searched and apart from a couple threads on RingCentral's own dev community where the question has not been answered clearly, I could not find anything on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reason for this like network issue, number of recipients, size of attached files, outrage etc.
I find similar question posted [here](https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/255/long-delay-in-fax-delivery.html)
You can ask devsupport@ringcentral.com to investigate the issue or can create a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending your faxes via the API, could you please provide the code you're using to achieve that goal in your question and how the code is failing to achieve the desired results in relation to the API documentation?

Otherwise, you will want to create a support case to receive help when not using the API or sending faxes programmatically with RingCentral.

StackOverflow is not customer support, it is developer questions (which means code is usually involved).